# How to differentiate Login from Sign up when using PassportJS for Facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, passport.js

I am trying to set up goals on Google Analytics to track Sign Ups, so I set up a 'thank you ' page as my url goal. It works well when my users sign up with their email address but not when they use facebook to sign up/login. When they login, they are redirected to the thank you page as there is only one url callback when setting up Facebook using Passport JS and Node.

Here is my code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  UserActivity.findOne(id,'uid ref', function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    clientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    callbackURL: "https://www.xxxxxxx.com/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //console.log(profile);
    User.findOne({ uid: profile.id }, function(err, uInfo) {
      if(err) console.log('Error: '+err);
      else{
        //User exists: we are done
        if(uInfo){
          done(err, uInfo);
        }
        else{
            //User doesn't exist: we create a new one
            var newUser = new User ({
              uid: profile.id,
              email:profile.emails[0].value,
              ref: 'Facebook'
            });
            // Saving it to the database.  
            newUser.save(function (err,uInfo) {
              if (err) console.log ('Error on save!');
              done(err, uInfo);
            });
        }
      }
    })
  }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/thankyou',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

If the user exists, I would like to redirect to their dashboard ('/dashboard) and if they are new users, I need to redirect them to /thankyou.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If user not exist `newUser = new User({isNewUser: true, ...});` and if user exists we can `uInfo.isNewUser = false; done(err, uInfo)`, check isNewUser in route later.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't want to use that because I didn't have direct access to the new user object in the callback. I could have read the database, but I would have to read and update the flag. 2 DB calls is too much just

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer.  Here is the updated code below. Pay attention to the use of passReqToCallback and req.session.newu

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
  {
    clientID: 'XXX',
    clientSecret: 'XXX',
    callbackURL: "https://www.XXX.co/auth/facebook/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //console.log(profile);
    User.findOne({ uid: profile.id }, function(err, uInfo) {
      if(err) console.log('Error: '+err);
      else{
        if(uInfo){
          done(err, uInfo);
        }
        else{
            var newUser = new User ({
              uid: profile.id,
              email:profile.emails[0].value,
              ref: 'Facebook'
            });
            // Saving it to the database.  
            newUser.save(function (err,uInfo) {
              if (err) console.log ('Error on save!');
              req.session.newu=true;
              done(err, uInfo);
            });
        }
      }
    })
  }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',function(req, res, next) {

  passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      var redLink = '/dashboard';
      if(req.session.newu)redLink = '/dashboard?newu'
      return res.redirect(redLink);
    });
  })(req, res, next);

});
```

An existing user will be redirected to /dashboard and a new user will be redirected to /dashboard?newu
Google Analytics doesn't need 2 different urls, it just needs a query string. When I set up the url goal, I selected url start with /dashboard?newu.

Hope this helps

Comment: Good to know `passReqToCallback` :) But don't you need to clear session.newu?

Comment: Thanks for noticing but I actually dont, clearing session.newu is done when the user logs out

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but it might still help someone like me. The OP's answer works but it means you have to take care of log-in user and session, etc. In case you still want to leave those work to PassportJS, use `req.session.returnTo` in strategy's callback with `successReturnToOrRedirect` option in `passport.authenticate()` would work.